# linking .so file in AndroidStudio 2.2.2

Tags: android-ndk, java-native-interface, .so

I am new to android ndk development.
I have a **.so** from which I have to access some native functions.

I m stucked in linking the **.so** in AndroidStudio 2.2.2 `gradle` `com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.8.2`

I googled a lot but none of the solution really helped me . I don't know where I am going wrong.

**my project structure**

[image]

**Android.mk**

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := libecho-prebuilt

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libecho.so

LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)

include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'
model{
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "anative.techmorphosis.com.nativedemo"
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel 16
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel 23
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            ndk {
                moduleName "netive_demo"
            }
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles.add(file('proguard-android.txt'))
            }
        }
        sourceSets.main {
            jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.skyfishjy.ripplebackground:library:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha1'
}
```

How do I import header files of **.so** library in my `audio_main.cpp`

while building project  I get **Error:Cause: com.android.build.gradle.managed.AndroidConfig$NodeView**

Comment: Google recommends switching to the official gradle plugin and using [`cmake` or `ndkBuild`](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html) in an `externalNativeBuild` block, rather than using the experimental plugin.

Comment: How do I build CmakeList.text for unknown .so file ?

Comment: You don't have to switch to using CMake. As they mention on the page I linked to you can still use your Android.mk and Application.mk files by using `ndkBuild` instead of `cmake` in your gradle script.